# How to assign primitive data types to custom classes directly in java

Tags: java

How do I create a wrapper class for a primitive data type such as int, boolean, and String?

I want to create my own classes that handle these types easier for when I'm doing my java projects.

```
    AltString s = "Hello world";
```

As opposed to calling the constructor:

```
    AltString s = new AltString("Hello world");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. Java doesn't allow you to define custom conversion operators (or indeed any operators).

(You can certainly create your own wrapper classes, but you can't make the assignment work the way you want.)

As a side-note, `String` isn't a primitive type. From the [Java Language Specification section 4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2):

> ```
> PrimitiveType:
>     NumericType
>     boolean
>
> NumericType:
>     IntegralType
>     FloatingPointType
>
> IntegralType: one of
>    byte short int long char
>
> FloatingPointType: one of
>     float double
> ```

Comment: also it should be noted that Strings aren't really primitive data types, they're Objects. they're just so commonly used that the designers allowed us to create them without having to call a constructor

Comment: @JeffHawthorne: True - will note that.

Comment: Thanks. Kind of hoping it wouldn't be that way, but that makes sense as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload operators in Java